# Slow signInAnonymously() and auth().currentUser.getIdToken()

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I'm using firebase to sign in anonymously in a react-native app. 
It takes up to 20s to respond to the `firebase.auth().signInAnonymouslyAndRetrieveData()` and to `firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()` after the token has expired.

There are no cloud functions set.

I'm using:

```
    "react-native": "^0.56.0",
    "react-native-firebase": "^4.2.0",
```

UPDATE:

Here where it gets stuck for a while

```
 W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
 W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzal@d101a93
 W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
 I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
 I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
```

Any suggestions on how to reduce the response time?

Comment: 1. Faster internet.  2. Faster client/browser.  Not much you can do otherwise.

Comment: It isn't a internet or a client issue as other requests to the server (that get data from firebase)  have a 200 ms response time.

Comment: Well, unless you're somehow tracing the *actual* call that's being made by the API (and not some other call), then you can't really know for sure.  Regardless, you have no other control over how the APIs work, in terms of performance.

Comment: One thing you can try is removing console.logs. Not sure about Android but they really bog down iOS - especially if you’re running it via Xcode